# Как реализовать правильно редирект с проверкой живых хостов в nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, geoip

Доброго времени суток!
Есть сервер балансировщик NGINX + GeoIP, требуется сделать редирект на сервера по странам, с проверкой живых серверов. 
Работают отдельно методы с GeoIP и upstream.
Как их правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```
geoip_country GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
geoip_city    GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat;
map $geoip_city_continent_code $nearest_server {
    default ru;
    EU      eu;
    NA      na;
}
server {
    listen 12346;
    proxy_pass $nearest_server;
}
upstream ru {
    server ru1.example.com:12345;
    server ru2.example.com:12345;
}
upstream eu {
    server eu1.example.com:12345;
    server eu2.example.com:12345;
}
upstream na {
    server na1.example.com:12345;
    server na2.example.com:12345;
}
```

В некоммерческой версии можно донастроить [`server`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server)-a для максимально быстрой реакции на упавший бекенд.

В коммерческой версии есть модуль [ngx_http_upstream_hc_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_hc_module.html#health_check) самостоятельно занимающийся проверкой работоспособности серверов.